# Why was this q downvoted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

So  here is my question -

[my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478100/black-sholes-from-probability-tree-hull-13a-6)

I can see it's been downvoted. I do not understand why. Is there some further detail I need to add? Downvoted questions tend to never get answers, and i do want to understand this particular math.

Comment: The question is fine. My guess would be that someone doesn't like the lack of TeX. But sometimes people downvote capriciously.

Comment: You've pasted a huge amount of text as an image instead, and then posted what should be equations as codeblock. Not only does this make accessibility all but impossible, it's an indicator of laziness to not even try using the correct formats of information.

Comment: You've referred to equations by numbering that doesn't even apply to the image you supplied, and supplying it as an image isn't that great to begin with. I think you have a genuine question there, and it's nice to provide all that context by citing the source, but you've put a lot of the work required to understand it on your readers.

Comment: My personal suggestion would be to cut it down to at most three equations, and that you do the work of eliminating all the "junk" variables, that don't matter to the phenomenon you're trying to understand. That said, I haven't fully digested your question, and I think that questions that are just grindy details, as opposed to interesting math phenomena, don't get as much attention.

Comment: @jon ok i eliminated the  junk variables - is this new version better?

Comment: @jon i referenced using an old pdf version, as taking a photo of the book produced too big an image to use on this site? but in the current book it is chapter 13, and in the online pdf it is chapter 12

Comment: @nij i have never used math jax before, i'm afraid. i am not a professional mathamatician.

Comment: One way to think about is that you're in a foreign country and the only way the natives understand you is if you use mathjax @bharal

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and the links there.

Comment: It looks much better now. But you could further improve it by heeding the comment @hardmath made on the original post.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion: I think the actual idea behind the question is good, but the way you have presented is not good. You should write up the question with relevant context from the book so that it could be answered and reviewed by the maximum range of people. What if someone has the same doubt but from reading a different book? If you don't present the required context properly they maybe confused and unable to derive value from your post

Also, there is another element which is not commonly discussed, and, that is of search engine optimization. If you write the details in plain text/math jax, they are more likely to come up in a search than as it is at the moment. Tl;dr: text is more searchable than images.

Anyhow I have given you a +1 in hopes that you will become a much more valuable contributor to the site in the future ^^

Comment: hi thanks - i added mathjax (i think? there is a small example of using $dollar signs$ at the right of the edit page) is this better?

Comment: i'm not sure how to tell math jax that $e^(x/n)$ is really exp(x/n), it seems to want to make it $(e^x) /n$

Comment: You have to go e^{x/n}. But there is help with formatting available elsewhere on this website.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference this is the math jax guide

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai i just updated it, is that better?\

Comment: Dang I can't possibly imagine why this meta answer got downvoted...

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai must be the faithful follower

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai one of my very old posts was downvoted immediately after this comment here. I wonder how, I wonder why...

Comment: Strange the same hapend to me to as well. @DatBoi

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai very strange indeed...

Comment: I'm not your downvoter, but I do see an inconsistency in telling the OP why context is needed and then both upvoting their Q and editing it in a way that, while providing MathJax formatting of a central part of the text image, considerably eliminated the little context that existed before.  As you will see, my comments with the OP produced some startling insights into what the context of the Q is.

Comment: You do raise a good point, but I don't think the original case had the specific information required for solving either